# Require specific return type

Tags: python

I have a situation, where I need require from another implementator, follow with my base class design:

```
class ExemplaryClass:
    pass

class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def process(self):
        # should return specific type, for instance ExemplaryClass
```

and derived class, which will be created by other programmer:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def process(self):
        # if return sth different from ExemplaryClass, should throw exception
```

How can I force programmer by the code, to follow my design?
In C++ and other language with static type control, this issue is pretty easy:

```
class ExemplaryClass {}

class Base{
public:
    virtual ExemplaryClass proccess() =0;
}

class Derived :public Base {
public:
    // ERROR
    void proccess() ovveride { }
}
```

But in the language with dynamic type control like python, this situation is very complicated, I have no idea so solve this issue.

Comment: How can i force programmer by the code, to follow my design? <- With firearms or through blackmailing.

Comment: The principles of duck-typing kind of forbid such hyper explicit typing. As long as `process` returns something that *acts like* `ExemplaryClass`, that's good enough. But you can use static type checking tools in Python 3.4+ to check *some* of that at least.

Comment: @timgeb while your answer is very funny, it's not accurate for Python 3.5+.

Comment: This question is far too broad for stackoverflow (i.e code reviews, code standards type hinting), perhaps a question for [programmers.se] but read their guidelines before posting.

Comment: @jpic are you referring to type-hinting? Because really, that requires a static-type-checker like `mypy`, otherwise, the programmer is free to break the contract implied by type-hints.

Comment: Seriously, though, you don't use a language like Python. If you want static type checking, use a language that has static-type checking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillagaso, can u propose me different solution to solve this problem? What will be occurred in situation, when programmer didn't follow my design?

Comment: @RobertPawlak you write good docstrings on what your code is supposed to do and what types it expects. In addition you can use the type hints other people mentioned. If anybody decides to ignore the docs and hints then they are on their own.

Comment: @Sayse when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat - True, this is partly why I like to remind people to read the other networks guidelines before posting because normally a sites tour gives a good idea of what questions are suitable for that site

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out in the comments, it's bad practice do such type checks. But if you really want to do it, you can split `process` into two methods - an abstract method and another method that calls the abstract method and validates its return value:

```
class Base(ABC):
    def process(self):
        result = self._process()
        assert isinstance(result, ExemplaryClass)
        return result

    @abstractmethod
    def _process(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally came up with a solution.

The idea is to implement `__getattribute__` in the main class, so has to modify the method called by the child class.

Consider two simple classes: a `Foo` base class, defined by the module, and a `Bar` subclass, defined by a user of the API.
The `Bar` class overwrites the `method` method, but you want it to return an object of type `int`, so as to keep the same behaviour as `Foo.method`.

```
class Foo:
    def method(self):
        return 1

class Bar(Foo):
    def method(self):
        return "a"
```

Of course, this is alright.
But here is a trick with the `__getattribute__` method.

I first check if the requested attribute is named `"method"`.
Then, if it is, instead of returning the actual `method`, I create a custom function, that additionnaly asserts that the return value of the actual `method` is an `int`.

```
def __getattribute__(self, attribute):
    if attribute == "method":

        def _f(*args, **kwargs):
           result = type(self).method(self, *args, **kwargs)
           assert isinstance(result, int)
           return result

        return _f
```

Now, the `__getattribute__` method is such defined that `instance.whatever` will result in a call to `instance.__getattribute__("whatever")`, regardless whether or not `whatever` could be found as an attribute of any class in its inheritance family.

As a consequence, if `bar = Bar()`, then `bar.method` will be replaced by the internal `_f` that I defined in `Foo.__getattribute__`.

Now, `bar.method()` will result in an `AssertionError`, but if I modify it as follows:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def method(self):
        return 1
```

then the execution will be fine.

---

Regarding the definition of `__getattribute__`, it might be a bit tricky, because you cannot call `self.something`, because it would result in a recursive call to `__getattribute__`.
The solution is to directly refer to `type(self).method`, which refers to the **class method** defined here by `Bar`.
In this case, this method takes an `instance` as first parameter, so `self` must be passed, hence the line:

```
result = type(self).method(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Of course, all of this will fail if the subclass itself implements `__getattribute__`.
But anyway, do not forget that a Python API is rather easy to break.
More specifically, the `AssertError` could be easily caught.
Well, you could replace `assert` by `sys.exit(1)`, but that might be a bit too coercitive...

---

I just got an idea.
This is more or less an anti-pattern, Python-wise, because it bans users from freely do what they want.
On the other hand, one could replace the `assert`/`raise` by a mere `print`, in order to *educate* users instead of *punishing* them.

Comment: I love the sheer audacity of this. But I hope if anyone actually tries it, that I don't ever have to maintain their code...

Comment: @trentcl Well, regarding exclusively the code design, this is the most anti-Pythonic I ever came up with, so... At least, it's fun!